GCP passing secrets from Secret Manager to .NET container using cloudbuild.yaml
I'm in the process of migrating my apps from a self-hosted server (without docker, just pure nginx routing and dot runs) to GCP Cloud Run, but I've hit a roadblock trying to access secrets from the Secret Manager.
I have added multiple secrets which contain values and are accessible via the Cloud Run IAM principle. I'm using cloudbuild.yaml to setup the pipelines and I've got the docker build working with the first couple of apps, but I'm unable to get the secrets flowing.
I setup a test step to ensure that the Cloud Build could at least read the secrets which worked:
steps:
  - id: 'Secrets in Pipeline'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    secretEnv: ['Urls_AuthIssuer']
    args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      echo "$$Urls_AuthIssuer"
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/Urls_AuthIssuer/versions/latest
    env: 'Urls_AuthIssuer'

However when I try and consume these at build time, the environment variables don't seem to be accessible to the .NET application:
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build','-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE_NAME', '-f', './WOML.WebAPI/Dockerfile', '.']

# Push the container image to Container Registry
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE_NAME']

# Deploy container image to Cloud Run
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args: ['run', 'deploy', '$_SERVICE_NAME', '--image', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE_NAME', '--region', '$_DEPLOY_REGION']
  secretEnv: [
    'Urls_AuthIssuer',
  ]

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/Urls_AuthIssuer/versions/latest
      env: 'Urls_AuthIssuer'
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE_NAME']

My dockerfile is very basic and is currently just a "copy all and run" for simplicity sake - I haven't tried to do anything clever in there yet to trim things down
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY . ./

RUN ls /src

RUN dotnet restore "WOML.WebAPI/WOML.WebAPI.csproj"

RUN dotnet publish "WOML.WebAPI/WOML.WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS final
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/build/WOML.WebAPI.dll"]

The build & deploy is successful, however the Cloud Run instance fails errors because it can't access any of the variables to perform setup. I added some log lines to try and read the variables and they're all empty.
Am I doing the secretEnv in the right step, or is there a better way to approach this? Should I add a step before the deployment which reads the secrets from Secret Manager and prints them out to an env file which the docker container can read? Most examples I find are small examples which suggest adding a -e variable to the run step for every single variable, which is not sustainable as the apps have many config settings and will only grow.

Have you checked the logs?  What do the logs show? Are you getting any error messages? Please edit the question by sharing the logs?

There aren't really any logs - the issue is that they're not accessible via the .NET app using either ConfigurationManager.GetValue() or Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(). The app will pass the build steps, but the Cloud Run instance will fall over because it's missing values where it's expecting them - for example Urls_AuthIssuer is null.
They're accessible during the cloud build steps, but it seems the Cloud Run container isn't being assigned the variables

A container is an isolated piece of software. The build also is. I mean, the build process do not know the external environment, variables, binaries and others. It's isolated, hermetic to the rest of the world!
If you want to push an external data into it, you must do it explicitly. You already provide the path . with your sources, and you also have to provide build args to push your env var.
In addition, event it would be too simple, the secrets in Cloud Build are only available in script mode, not in args mode.
Here, I mean you have to perform something like this
args:
  - -c
  - |
    <your script>

and not
args: [my, script, args]

You can find more detail in an already answered question here

I get that they're separate, the docker examples I've traced are passing the variables individually in the args. Perhaps a better approach for me is a script to print the secrets to a file and pass the file into the Docker container? Alternatively, I could simplify this further by just having the apps read directly from the Secret Manager if there's an API (I haven't checked yet)

If you use Cloud Run, it's simpler, you can read your secret from env var or from files mounted on the file system, and the Cloud Run runtime perform the read from secret, and the load into the destination. So, it's transparent for you!
